# Is there a way I can fix this parse error I am having

Tags: haskell

I get a parse error in pattern: `sumSales` on `sumSales store day (company,[(d,sales)]): y`. I am new to haskell and do not know what this error could be

[image]

```
sumSales::(Num p,Eq t) => t -> t -> [(t,[(t,p)])] -> p
sumSales store day (company,[(d,sales)]): y
    | store == company && day == d = sales + sumSales store day y
    | otherwise = getSales day y
```

Comment: Add brackets between `(company,[(d, sales)]) : y)`, right now the compiler assumes you define a `(:)` function.

Comment: But nevertheless, right now the patterns are not complete, for example, an empty list for the last parameter is not processed.

Comment: `[(d, sales)]` is a list of length exactly one. What about all the other lists? This looks like a bad idea. Turn on warnings, and listen to them: handle _all_ cases. You are probably pattern matching too soon.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem all the other lists are in (y)

Comment: @K-Genma: yes, but you recurse on `y`. Eventually `y` will be exhausted (an empty list), so it will make a recursive call `sumSales store day []`, and then that will no longer pattern match on the `(company, [(d, sales)])`. Furthermore as chi says, `[(d, sales)]` will only fire if the first item contains a *singleton* list.

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell, pattern matches must be enclosed in parentheses. The parser reads

```
sumSales store day (company, [(d, sales)]) : y
```

as a definition of `(:)`, not a definition of `sumSales`. This then produces a parse error because you cannot put more than one argument on each side of the operator, and this definition appears to have four arguments on the left (`sumSales`, `store`, `day`, and `(company, [(d, sales)])`). You should rewrite to

```
sumSales store day ((company, [(d, sales)]) : y)
```

As several commentors on the OP point out, there are a number of other problems with the code, but this will at least solve the parse error.